# How do I randomly sort groups of multiple lines in a multi-GB file?

Tags: sorting

I've got a multi-GB file that has elements in 4 lines, and I would like to have every 4 lines randomized in another file, this is, keeping each four lines grouped and randomize those sets. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to keep the four lines grouped and randomize those sets, or do you want randomize the four lines but keep the groups in order?

Comment: keep each group of four lines grouped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a reasonable new linux/unix distribution, [`sort`](http://fclose.com/p/linux/man/1-sort/) comes with a `-R` flag which randomises lines instead of sorts them. We can use that to create this one-liner solution:

```
awk '{printf("%s%s",$0,(NR%4==0)?"\n":"\0")}' file.txt | sort -R | tr "\0" "\n" > sorted.txt
```

First, use `awk` to group every 4 lines by replacing `\n` with `\0`. We then shuffle the lines using `sort -R` and finally restore the line breaks with `tr`.

Comment: The `"\n` is unclosed and should be `"\n"`. I can't make such a small edit, so I'm just putting it here.

Comment: Also, for some reason on my system, I couldn't printf the "\0" and get it to replace properly. Instead, I used `printf("%s%c",$0,(NR%4==0)?"\n":0)`. I did not need to change the tr command.

Answer (score 1):

This is in Python.  I'm sure someone will post a Perl answer too. ;-)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random

#Change these to the desired files
infile = "/path/to/input/file"
outfile = "/path/to/output/file"

fh = file(infile)
contents = fh.readlines()
fh.close()

chunked = [contents[i:i+4] for i in xrange(0, len(contents), 4)]
random.shuffle(chunked)

fh = file(outfile, 'w')

for chunk in chunked:
    for line in chunk:
        fh.write(line)

fh.close()
```

IANA Programmer so somebody could probably improve this, but I tested it and it works just fine.