# Sorting HTML content based on second line of table cell

Tags: bash, html, sorting

I have an Windows text file, containing the text of an HTML table (no header, no footer) with each cell of the table not in alpha order. I'd like to alphabetize the tables, a la:

```
REDACTED-TITLE-1 REDACTED-TITLE-2 REDACTED-TITLE-3 REDACTED-TITLE-4 REDACTED-TITLE-5  
REDACTED-TITLE-6 REDACTED-TITLE-7 REDACTED-TITLE-8 REDACTED-TITLE-9 REDACTED-TITLE-A 
REDACTED-TITLE-B REDACTED-TITLE-C REDACTED-TITLE-D REDACTED-TITLE-E REDACTED-TITLE-F
```

The cells are in the format:

```
<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-1">
REDACTED-TITLE-1</A></td>

<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-2">
REDACTED-TITLE-2</A></td>

<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-3">
REDACTED-TITLE-3</A></td>

<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-4">
REDACTED-TITLE-4</A></td>

<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-5">
REDACTED-TITLE-5</A></td>

<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-6">
REDACTED-TITLE-6</A></td>

<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-7">
REDACTED-TITLE-7</A></td>

<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-8">
REDACTED-TITLE-8</A></td>

<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-9">
REDACTED-TITLE-9</A></td>

<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-A">
REDACTED-TITLE-A</A></td>

<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-B">
REDACTED-TITLE-B</A></td>

<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-C">
REDACTED-TITLE-C</A></td>

<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-D">
REDACTED-TITLE-D</A></td>

<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-E">
REDACTED-TITLE-E</A></td>

<td><A HREF="https://REDACTED-URL-F">
REDACTED-TITLE-F</A></td>
```

and so forth.

May I use command-line commands in Windows, or PowerShell commands, to sort that couplet on the contents of the text description, i.e., REDACTED-TITLE-*n* ?  Or, may I use Excel?

I know I will need to put the tr and /tr tags back in after the list is sorted and stuff the sorted lines back in to the table.

Comment: You need to show more of the table. Do you want to sort just the cells per each, or do you want to sort all the cells and then arrange them in rows?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, and I suspect that nobody else does, either. What do the A1 and B2 have to do with the ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO? What does "second line of table cell" have to do with the rest of the question? Do you mean "second line of table cell" or "second row of the table"? What's the input and what's the output? What else are you not telling us?

Comment: I suspect that [How do I randomly sort groups of multiple lines in a file?](http://superuser.com/q/304920/150988) is similar to what you're asking. See if it helps you.

Comment: Well, found my workplace does not have and will not permit bash tools, so I am limited to PowerShell and Windows command-line tools. Therefore, that does not help.

Comment: Do you have access to Excel? And does this need to be fully automatable or is a manual process ok?

Comment: Missed the edit deadline, along with part of the question. You may also want to look into vbscript text processing, likely also available if PowerShell is and more likely to have a large existing base of text processing code.

Comment: Excel OK. And, delete the old post if it's past the edit deadline and add into new post. I often combine multiple comments that way as I fumble towards solving issues here.